# Why does the value of my query change when it's not supposed to?

Tags: c#, .net, web, blazor

I'm working on a blazor webpage for an assignment where you can add, view and search for adult objects that are stored in a json file.
I'm working on the search function right now and I've encountered a problem. I tried to create an IEnumerable query which starts out as the full list of adults and is then checked against every search criteria and if the criteria is not empty, it narrows the query down to a list of adults with that criteria. For some reason, after checking the first criteria, the value of the query changes from 42 (the length of the adult list) to this: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<Assignment_1.Models.Adult>}

How can I fix that, so in the end all that remains is a list of adults who fulfill all the criteria entered?

```
@inject Assignment_1.Models.AdultManager adultManager;

@page "/search"
<h3>Search for adults</h3>

<form>
    <label for="firstname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" @bind-value="firstName">
    <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" @bind-value="lastName"><br>
    <label for="haircolor">Haircolor</label>
    <select id="haircolor" @bind="hairColor">
        <option disabled selected value></option>
        <option value="blonde">Blonde</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
    <label for="eyecolor">Eyecolor</label>
    <select id="eyecolor" @bind="eyeColor">
        <option disabled selected value></option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="amber">Amber</option>
        <option value="hazel">Hazel</option>
    </select><br>


    <label for="height">Height</label>
    <input type="text" id="height"  @bind-value="height">
    <label for="weight">Weight</label>
    <input type="text" id="weight"  @bind-value="weight"><br>

    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="age"  @bind-value="age">
    <label>Sex</label>
    <input type="radio" id="m" name="gender" value="M" @onchange="genderSelected">
    <label for="m">M</label>
    <input type="radio" id="f" name="gender" value="F" @onchange="genderSelected">
    <label for="f">F</label>
    <button type="button" @onclick="search">Search</button>




</form>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Haircolor</th>
            <th>Eyecolor</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Job</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (searchedAdult!=null) 
        { foreach (Assignment_1.Models.Adult adult in searchedAdult)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@adult.FirstName</td>
                <td>@adult.LastName</td>
                <td>@adult.Id</td>
                <td>@adult.HairColor</td>
                <td>@adult.EyeColor</td>
                <td>@adult.Age</td>
                <td>@adult.Weight</td>
                <td>@adult.Height</td>
                <td>@adult.JobTitle</td>
                <td>@adult.Sex</td>
            </tr>

            } 
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
@code {
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string hairColor;
    public string eyeColor;
    public string weight;
    public string height;
    public string jobTitle;
    public string age;
    public string sex;
    public List<Models.Adult> searchedAdult;


    private void search()
    {

        IEnumerable<Models.Adult> query = adultManager.getAllAdults();
        if (firstName != null || firstName!="")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName == firstName);
        }
        if (lastName != null || lastName!="")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.LastName==lastName);
        }
        if (hairColor != null || hairColor!="")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.HairColor == hairColor);
        }
        if (eyeColor != null || eyeColor != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.EyeColor == eyeColor);
        }
        if (weight != null || weight != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Weight.ToString() == weight);
        }
        if (height != null || height != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Height.ToString() == height);
        }
        if (jobTitle != null || jobTitle != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.JobTitle == jobTitle);
        }
        if (age != null || age != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Age.ToString() == age);
        }
        if (sex != null || sex != "")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Sex == sex);
        }

        searchedAdult = query.ToList();

    }
    private void genderSelected(ChangeEventArgs a)
    {
        sex= a.Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `For some reason, after checking the first criteria, the value of the query changes from 42` because your call to `adultManager.getAllAdults()` returns 42 instances. Then when filtering again with the `where` it returns an IEnumerable<Models.Adult> that contains elements from the input sequence that satisfy the condition. You can check `query.Count` to see how many elements actually exist after the filter.

Comment: But if add a criteria then check for the query list at the end, it's always empty even if there should be adults who fulfill the criteria.

Comment: `But if add a criteria then check for the query list at the end, it's always empty`, have you set breakpoints to see where your query may be going wrong?

Comment: It's going to as you've applied a filter that hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: Yes. When I initialize the query, it return 42 instances but right after the first filter, it writes this instead: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<Assignment_1.Models.Adult>}
It seems like even if the values is null it goes into the if statement or else I don't know why the value would change.

Comment: The query object is changing because you're adding a filter (`where`). As the answer provided below, check for strings like `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)`

Comment: Then how to I execute the filter?

Comment: Call `.ToList()` on it. But if you just want to check how many items are in there, you can check the `Count` property. Why do you want to execute the query after every check?

Comment: ToList() or ToArray(), some function that enumerates the query

Comment: Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, after checking the first criteria, the value of the query changes from 42 (the length of the adult list) to this: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<Assignment_1.Models.Adult>}

```
query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName == firstName);
```

This does not execute the query it only defines one.

> {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<Assignment_1.Models.Adult>}

To execute you need to call `ToList()` for example.

Side Note:
`if (firstName != null || firstName!="")`

could be written as

`if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))`

In C# 9.0 Currently in rc2

`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) is not true)`

It's a coding style thing...

```
   @if (searchedAdult!=null) 
        { foreach (Assignment_1.Models.Adult adult in searchedAdult)
            {
            <tr>
```

You should use @key here as well.

```
@foreach(var adult in searchedAdult ?? Array.Empty<Adult>())
{
    <tr @key="adult">
```